# Page load in jQuery to new page in WorkLight

Tags: javascript, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to redirect to a new page when the current page loads. I am using jQuery mobile with WorkLight.

### Index.html:

```
<body>
   <div data-role="importpages" id="pageport">
   </div>
</body>
```

### Login.html:

```
<body>  
    <a>simple</a>
    <div data-role="page" id="loginpage" style="background-color: #C7BABA;" >           
    </div>
</body>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pageport').load('Login.html',function() {
        alert('load');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery mobile, check out the Pagecontainer widget section which talks about the newer version of page loading.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load

However, keep in mind that IBM Worklight apps are meant to be single page apps due to the scripts that load on the original page. However, there are methodologies for loading framents and utilizing a multipage set up.

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_07_5_-_Building_a_Multi_Page_Application.pdf

I would be careful about redirecting the page completely because of the possible of issues that could arise from losing the right Worklight scripts.

Although you are probably asking and meaning more of a single page DOM injection, I am just providing the information for anyone that may read this in the future. You mentioned redirection and I wanted to be clear. =)

Comment: Oh how I wish the company that put out Worklight followed its own rules regarding single page mobile apps *coughcough*

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function changePage in jqm.

```
  $.mobile.changePage("index.html",{});
```